# ¿Cómo saber si llegó a la última página en MatPaginator?

Tags: angular, datatables

Estoy utilizando Data tables con `MatPaginator` en angular material y quisiera realizar una acción cuando el usuario llegue al final de las paginas de la `dataTable`, este es mi código de HTML

```
    </table>
</div>
<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[10,10, 15, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
```

Y este es  mi TypeScript

```
  constructor(private visorOracle: VisorService) { }  
    paginaActual:Number = 10; 
    fechaActual:number; 
  displayedColumns = [   
    'UBICACION',
    'FECHHA_HORA',
    'NOMBRE_PACIENTE',
    'UBINOM', 
  ];
    dataSource: any; 
        @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;
        ngOnInit() {

      this.envio(this.seleccionada);
     setInterval(() => {
       this.fechaActual = Date.now(); 
  }, 10); 

  }  
  enviosamu(){ 

    this.envio(this.seleccionada);
        setInterval(() => {
      this.envio(this.seleccionada)
      ;
      console.log('Recarga',this.recarga);
      this.recarga = this.recarga + 1
  }, 45000); 
 ;

  }

  envio(Samu){ 
     this.visorOracle.getPacientes(Samu).subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log('llegaron ',res);
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
        this.dataSource.data = res; 
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;


        // alertify.success('DATOS CARGADOS ');    
          setInterval(() => {
            if (this.paginaActual < this.paginator.length){
              this.paginator.nextPage();
              this.paginaActual =+ this.paginaActual +10  ;
              console.log('nex pague',this.paginator.length, this.paginaActual);
            }else{
              // this.paginaActual = (this.paginaActual - 10 ) ;
              this.paginator.previousPage();
              console.log('previus pague', this.paginaActual);
            }
```

Está haciendo una iteración cada 10 segundos y me cambia la página el tema es que no se si llega a la página final para regresar a la pagina index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por defecto, `mat-paginator` muestra 50 items por página. Con este dato y sabiendo el total de datos puedes calcular si se ha llegado a la última página.

Para saber en que página estas `mat-paginator` emite un output con un evento cada vez que se cambia de página puedes escuchar ese evento. Este evento tienes las siguientes propiedades:

```
{previousPageIndex: 0, pageIndex: 0, pageSize: 10, length: 100 }
```

Se escucha el evento `page`

```
<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[10,10, 15, 25, 100]" (page)="pageChange($event)"></mat-paginator>
```

En el ts

```
// se calcula el índice final
// el indice inicial es 0  por eso se resta -1
// lo he puesto aquí pero deberías calcularlo cuando haya seteado el valor de dataSource
lastPageIndex = (this.dataSource.data.length/ this.pageSize) - 1;
pageChange(e: PageEvent) {
  console.log(e);
  if (e.pageIndex === this.lastPageIndex) {
    alert('last');
  }
}
```

[MatPaginator docs](https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api)